# Cannot use SnapAgent alone?

Tags: arcobjects, editing

I'm trying to use a standalone snap agent. Is that not possible?

Here's some code:

```
        // instantiate these agents.
        _snapSupportAgent = new FeatureSnapClass();
        _snapSupportAgent.FeatureClass = _parcelSplitLine;
        _snapSupportAgent.HitType = esriGeometryHitPartType.esriGeometryPartBoundary;

        _snapParcelAgent = new FeatureSnapClass();
        _snapParcelAgent.FeatureClass = _parcelSplitLine;
        _snapParcelAgent.HitType = esriGeometryHitPartType.esriGeometryPartBoundary;
```

Later on code:

```
        var newPoint = new PointClass();
        _snapParcelAgent.Snap(null,newPoint,1);
```

When I do that, I get a nasty protected memory exception. I'm editing directly to a IWorkspaceEdit, without interference of the IEditor.

Comment: Did you try using IEngineSnapAgent instead?  There's a sample [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001mv000000.htm).

Comment: I'll try that, but it's not an engine application. It's working under a custom form with a AxMapControl, true, but it's not ArcEngine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find the documentation now, but AFAIK, Snapping can only be done using the ISnapEnvironment Interface via the IEditor.

The IFeatureSnap is used in two kinds of cases: Defining a custom snap agents or accessing the snap agents in the snap environment. It is the snap environment which actually does the snapping.